# pushViewController do a black view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

I have a map that shows a lot annotations, and when I tap on `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` in the callout `annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView` I will get an empty black view.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"%@", view.annotation.title);
    MapPoint *annView = view.annotation;
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    dvc.titleLabel.text = annView.title;
    dvc.textView.text = annView.subtitle;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

**Edit**: 
I am using Storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Xib Interface then you should assign the NibName before pushing it on the stack.

**Using IB**

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

**Using StoryBoard**

Make sure you have defined the **Identifier** as "DetailViewController" for your viewController in attributes Inspector.

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

Comment: Just see the answer, it is not difficult to initialize using storyboard either.

Answer (score 0):

You should open storyboard and check if view controller custom class is filled correctly[image: c]

[image: custom class property]

Comment: is every component in your view transparent?=)